# Entity Framework include children that grand children are null

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

Seem like a simple one, but not coming up with the right thing.  All that I need to do is get a count of child items that have it's own child null.  Here is what I have been working with:

```
var data = await _context.award.Include(a => a.expenses.Select(p => p.invoice == null)).ToListAsync();
```

I have also tried other combinations here with no luck. The error I get is

> InvalidOperationException: The property expression 'a => {from expense p in [a].expenses select ([p].invoice == null)}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.

I change it to match and it just triggers a new error.

I just want to get a list of `award` with it's list of `expenses` listed (fine with just the `.ID` if that influences the solution) where the `invoice` parent object is not set and is `null`.

**UPDATE**
requested models

```
public class invoice
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("INV_NUM_ForeignKey")]
    public invoice_number fin_invoice_number { get; set; }
}

public class invoice_number
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int number { get; set; }

    public invoice invoice { get; set; }

    public string display { get { return string.Format("sps-{0}", (new String('0', 6) + number.ToString())).Substring(number.ToString().Count()-7, number.ToString().Count()); } }
}
```

Comment: Should tag be EF-Core instead of EF-6 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `.Include` together with `.ThenInclude`. Docs explains it clearly [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) (Including multiple levels).

```
var data = await _context.award
    .Include(a => a.expenses)
        .ThenInclude(e => e.invoice)
    .ToListAsync();
```

**Notice**: But notice, that `ThenInclude` has two overloads and chances are big, that Visual Studio will select the wrong one or just display one (wrong one) and give you either errors while typing or do not offer autocompetition for `e` if e is not a collection. If you ignore the error and type the correct property and close the bracket, the error will disappear.

Comment: the gets me `ArgumentException: The property expression 'e => (e.invoice == null)' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. `

Comment: Remove the brackets

Comment: And what's your model?

Comment: added it to the question

Comment: This only exists in EF Core, not EF 6.

Comment: @madannes: `.Include` does exist in EF6. Just the `ThenInclude` syntax is different and with a `.Select` inside the `Include`, i.e. `.Include(a => a.expenses.Select(e => e.invoice)`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I posted too quickly =) By **"This"** I meant `.ThenInclude()` only exists in EF Core. Your way is how I've done hierarchical eager fetching in EF 6 as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you know what you are doing but 
sometimes it happens and a magic letter solves nightmare problems...

Generally (Which version of EF you use dunno),
as far as i know, like described here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Check your model has related properties
Decide Eagerly or Lazy ...

If thesee are not solution then switch your computer :)..
Then Just in EF configuration check relation definitions

Sorry still can not comment out.I had to write answer...

Answer (score -1):

Try re-writing your code like this

```
var data = await _context.award.Include(a => a.expenses).Where(p => p.expenses.Any(a => a.invoice == null)).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using .Net 6.

If `.ThenInclude` is throwing error as your the parent is null. Then you can try this:

```
.Include(parent => parent.child)
.Include(parent => parent.child != null ? parent.child.grandChild : null);
```

Comment: Clearly not tested.

Comment: It's working, I have tested it in a project.

Comment: Maybe it does in your case (I got an exception in EFC7 telling that the expression is not a navigation property). But another objection is that it's not necessary because a `null` parent doesn't throw an exception. Also, its not related to the question which is about EF6 (old EF). In EF core the question could maybe be answered by a filtered `Include`, not `ThenInclude` or similar things. But probably just a projection would do it.