# Querying EF Core one-to-many and further one-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have 3 models, `Competition`, `Team` and `TeamUser`. Each Competition has many teams and each team has many users. I want to use EF Core to bind all 3 together when returning the data to the view, but I can't really bind to users. Thus I have to implement some complex logic at my view which although it works, looks super messy and confusing. I'm sure there's a way to return the data together.

`Competition` model class:

```
public class Competition
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Competition Name")]
    public string CompetitionName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}
```

`Team` model class:

```
public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public int TeamID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Team Name")]
    public string TeamName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompetitionID")]
    public int CompetitionID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TeamUser> TeamUsers { get; set; }

}
```

`TeamUser` model class:

```
public class TeamUser
{
    [Key]
    public int TeamUserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
     var competition = _context.Competitions
         .Include(c => c.Teams)
         .ToList();

     var teamUsers = _context.TeamUsers
         .ToList();

     if (competition == null)
     {
         return NotFound();
     }

     CompetitionIndexViewModel vm = new CompetitionIndexViewModel();
     vm.Competition = competition;
     vm.TeamUsers = teamUsers;

     return View(vm);
}
```

As you can see it is very messy and I have to resort to using viewmodel to get my data over. Hope there is a simpler solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: And what's messy about it (other than that this code is in the controller and not abstracted and you are returning all data unfiltered, = much data)? Using a view model is a valid approach and exactly what view models are made for, to bring data into a shape for a view to consume it (its bad practice anyways to use entities directly in views or as WebAPI results)

Comment: I don't fully understand your first line. So sorry... "And what's messy about it (other than that this code is in the controller and not abstracted and you are returning all data unfiltered, = much data)?"

Comment: Are you seeking for `ThenInclude`?

Comment: Yes absolutely. I tried that just now but it was flagging some errors. Now I went back to check it's working!

Comment: @zzdhxu: The errors are only intellisense errors, because `.ThenInclude` can't determine if you want a singlular or plural include (on T or Collection of T). Visual Studios Itellisense has issues there and may either not give you any intellisense or intellisense errors. You just need to continue typing. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42547524/entity-framework-include-children-that-grand-children-are-null/42548720#42548720)

Comment: I see thanks for sharing! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `CompetitionIndexViewModel`. Just write your query as follows and pass the `List<Competition>` to the View.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
     List<Competition> competitions = _context.Competitions
         .Include(c => c.Teams).ThenInclude(t => t.TeamUsers)
         .ToList();

     return View(competitions);
}
```

Now in the view each `Competition` should have a list of `Teams` and each `Team` should have a list of `TeamUsers`.

Comment: I tried that just now but it wasn't working. Just tried again and it's working weird...

Comment: How would you filter, for example, if you wanted only teams with a specific name?

Comment: When I did this, i want to return only a certain fields, for example, competition name and a list of teams in this competition. But it's returning duplicate data. for example, one competition has 5 teams and another competition has 2 teams. My query returns 7 records total. Each record has 1 team instead of 2 records, one has 5 and another has 2. I examine the query and it's doing a select on competition name, team id, team name, left joining the team table. This is what i have: var competitions = _context.Competitions.Include(c => c.Teams).Select(t => new { t.name, t.Teams });